# WordPress Contact Form 7 - different redirect pages for drop-down selection

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need your help.
I would like to redirect to a specific page due to a checkbox selection. The Form is transferred correctly, but does not redirect to the appropriate Page after submit. I have entered the Javascript code directly into Contactform 7. (see picture 1) Can you help for a moment?

Contactform 7 Shortcode and Javascript:

`[checkbox Auswahl id:eauswahl use_label_element default:0 "50€" "100€" "200€" "500€"]`

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event )  {
    if ( '2539' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {

     var aAuswahl =  document.getElementById("eauswahl").value;

        if (aAuswahl == "50€") {
        location = 'http://localhost/dwp/danke1/';
      } if else (aAuswahl == "100€") {
        location = 'http://localhost/dwp/danke2/';
      } if else (aAuswahl == "200€") {
        location = 'http://localhost/dwp/danke3/';
      } if else (aAuswahl == "500€") {
        location = 'http://localhost/dwp/danke4/';
      }
    }
}, false )
</script>
```

[Contact Form 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC2Zd.png)

[Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciC4S.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. I put this in functions.php file.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   console.log(event.detail);   
   if ( '2028' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
        console.log(event.detail.inputs[5].value);
        if (event.detail.inputs[5].value == '2021') {
           location = 'https://example.com/wp- 
           content/uploads/Brochure-2021.pdf';
        }
        if (event.detail.inputs[5].value == '2020') {
           location = 'https://example.com/wp- 
           content/uploads/Brochure-2020.pdf';
        }
    } 
   }, false );
   </script>
```